# Why date input turns into text in abp

Tags: c#, razor-pages, abp

I got this property in my class

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Display(Name = "Data da Assinatura")]
[Range(typeof(DateTime), "1/1/1900", "1/1/2079", ErrorMessage = "Valor de {0} tem que estar entre {1} e {2}")]
public DateTime DataAssinatura { get; set; }
```

;

```
<abp-input asp-for="Contrato.DataAssinatura" />
```

but when the page is rendered, it is converted to text.

```
<label class="form-label" for="Contrato_DataAssinatura">Data da Licitação</label><input type="text" data-val="true" data-val-range="Valor de Data da Licitação tem que estar entre 01/01/1900 00:00:00 e 01/01/2079 00:00:00" data-val-range-max="01/01/2079 00:00:00" data-val-range-min="01/01/1900 00:00:00" data-val-required="The Data da Licitação field is required." id="Contrato_DataAssinatura" name="Contrato.DataAssinatura" value="2022-05-10" class="form-control "><span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Contrato.DataAssinatura" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

Comment: Not 100% sure (never used abp helper tags), but shouldn't that attribute be `[DataType(DataType.Date)]`? AFAIK, `DataType(string)` works for custom data types and templates, not for standard ones

Comment: (additional info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatypeattribute.-ctor?view=net-6.0#overloads and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatype?view=net-6.0 )

Comment: @jcl sorry, the question was wrong. I already corrected.

Comment: I've made some tests and it seems to happen also on standard asp.net helper tag: seems it's rendered with an input type=text, and it just changes the locale date format. Seems to be standard